# How to create floating textfield like of gmail in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, gmail, textfield, floating

I need to create a floating textfield like Gmail for my iOS app, swift. How can I achieve this ?
I used to use `JVFloatLabeledTextField` previously but its not similar to what I wanted. I need to create something like in this image, where placeholder breaks the textfield border.[image]

Comment: Gotta draw it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has created a [Material Design Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios) you can use.

The picture you sent is their **MDCTextInputControllerOutlined** view.

Comment: Thank you it worked. I have implemented. Btw currently struggling to change the border width and border rounded corner radius for the textfield. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have not tried it sorry. But it appears that their material design library has its own stack overflow tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/material-components+ios

Answer (score 2):

**Podfile:**

```
#Material Design for UIComponents.
pod 'MaterialComponents'
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import MaterialComponents

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textFld_EmailId: MDCTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFld_Password: MDCTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFld_MobileNo: MDCTextField!

// MARK: Properties
var emailIdController: MDCTextInputControllerOutlined?
var passwordController: MDCTextInputControllerOutlined?
var mobileNoController: MDCTextInputControllerOutlined?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    emailIdController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: textFld_EmailId)
    passwordController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: textFld_Password)
    mobileNoController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: textFld_MobileNo)

  }
}
```

[image: Output Image]

Comment: depricated code